# Easiest way to sum numbers in a given format

Tags: metadata

I have a long list like this,

```
26m
26m
27m
28m
28m
28m
29m
29m
29m
2h 0m
2h 10m
2h 10m
2h 17m
2h 19m
2h 21m
```

I want to calculate the total duration using any software, what's the easiest way to do this, I am not best person to work with EXCEL.

Comment: First thing you need to do is convert all values to the same format, then do the math on the whole, then convert it to whatever type you want it to be. In your case, working with minutes is probably the best. So 2h 0m becuse 120m, 2h 10m becomes 120+10=130. Once you have all the values, remove all the m's from the notations so you have only the number itself. Then sum it all up to one number. If you want to use hours, divide the total amount of minutes by 60. You probably get a number such as 14.6 or so. Substract the whole number from the result, so 14.6-14 = 0.6. The remaining number * 60

Comment: " I am not best person to work with EXCEL." without using excel.. what software do you plan to work with? (That may help on guiding the others to help..)

Comment: Also, what have you tried? What research have you done? Are you just trying to sum the total time in the column? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @music2myear I already answered my question 22 hours ago, and your comment is 16 hours old, did you even read it ?

Comment: A) The review queue where I encountered you question does not show answers. B) The best questions on SuperUser show all necessary information and are helpful to others who may be searching in the future for similar problems they are experiencing. This means that simply having an answer is not the only goal, but being good enough to help others is also a goal. We're happy you solve your problem and shared it here, but the answer would be more effective if the question were more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split the list into two using a online service. Google "Split words online"

It gave me a list like this,

```
10m
2h
1m
4m
1h
```

I then used Notepad++ to bookmark and cut all lines which has letter "m", then moved them to a new sheet, then remove letter "m" from the document leaving only numbers. Then using another online service I was able to sum all numbers.

I did same for hours. It sounds a lot but only took a minute or so.